# Why polygonal numbers have $n^{th}$ term as this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

Why do the sequences of $s$-polygonal numbers have $n^{th}$ terms as below?

> If a polygon has $s$ sides, then the corresponding $n^{th}$ polygonal number is $$\frac{ (s-2)\times n^2 - (s-4)\times n  }{ 2}$$

Comment: One simple search on Wikipedia would more than answer your question: the induction is formula is written there.

Comment: There's an edit pending, but note that the numerator should be $(s-2)n^2 - (s-4)n$, not $(s-2)n^2+(s-4)n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write $P_s(n)$ for the $n^\text{th}$ $s$-polygonal number. We also take $P_s(0)=0$.

First of all, check out the diagrams in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number) on polygonal numbers. Notice how these polygons are built up. At each stage, we form a larger polygon by adding points along $s-2$ of the sides. At the $n^\text{th}$ stage of this process, each side has $n$ points along it. That means, when we added points along $s-2$ sides, the number of points we added was $$(\text{sides added})\times (\text{points on a side})-(\text{overlaps between sides})=(s-2)n-(s-3).$$ In other words, we have $P_s(n)-P_s(n-1)=(s-2)n-(s-3).$ This is a linear function of $n$ and we are working with a fixed $s$, so we see that the sequence in question has linear differences between its terms. Thus each $P_s(n)$ is an arithmetic series and you can use the formula $1+2+\dots+n=n(n+1)/2$ (corresponding to triangular numbers) to prove the general formula for polygonal numbers. Of course, this requires  you to prove the formula for triangular numbers by a different method, but this has a simple pictorial proof (also can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)). Alternatively, one may avoid calculations for high $n$ by using a little knowledge of [finite differences](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteDifference.html). Since the sequence $n\mapsto P_s(n)$ has linear differences, it is quadratic in $n$. But any quadratic is determined by three of its values, so it suffices to check that your formula yields the correct value for the three smallest cases:
$$P_s(0)=0,\qquad P_s(1)=1,\qquad P_s(n)=s.$$